# Property list data not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, properties

**Gateway.cs Page**

```
public class gatewayConnectionPropertyData
{

public string url { get; set; }
public int type { get; set; }
public string service_desc { get; set; }

}

protected void btnAddEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

gatewayConnectionPropertyData proposal = new gatewayConnectionPropertyData();
proposal.url = "/testproposal.xml";
proposal.type = 13;
proposal.service_desc = "proposal";

gatewayConnectionPropertyData utility = new gatewayConnectionPropertyData();
proposal.url = "/testUtulity.xml";
proposal.type = 12;
proposal.service_desc = "utility";

gatewayConnectionPropertyData intelligence = new gatewayConnectionPropertyData();
proposal.url = "/testinteligence.xml";
proposal.type = 53;
proposal.service_desc = "intelligence";


List<gatewayConnectionPropertyData> mydataList = new List<gatewayConnectionPropertyData>(); 
gatewayConnectionPropertyDataList.Add(proposal); 
gatewayConnectionPropertyDataList.Add(utility); 
gatewayConnectionPropertyDataList.Add(intelligence); 

}
```

**mydataList** always count 3 however only appear l**ast added item** i can **not see all datas** where i miss what do i need to change.If any opinion i can apply on my side for **better solution in order to create property list model** .

Thanks.

Comment: You are adding items in `gatewayConnectionPropertyDataList` what is it? and not in `mydataList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are adding items in `gatewayConnectionPropertyDataList` (I am not sure what it is) but if you are expecting the data in  `mydataList` you need to add in this variable only. Also, you can use `collection initializers` for this like this:-

```
List<gatewayConnectionPropertyData> mydataList = 
                                new List<gatewayConnectionPropertyData>
{
  new gatewayConnectionPropertyData { url = "/testproposal.xml", type = 13, 
                                             service_desc = "proposal" },
  new gatewayConnectionPropertyData { url = "/testUtulity.xml", type = 12, 
                                             service_desc = "utility" },
  new gatewayConnectionPropertyData { url = "/testinteligence.xml", type = 53,
                                             service_desc = "intelligence" },
};
```